# Am I releasing the memory in the heap correctly?

Tags: c++, delete-operator

I'm studying C/C++ and the exercise I'm doing is to create a program which evaluates an arithmetic expression.

To complete the exercise, I need a general purpose function which is able to tokenize a string.
As the size of the string to parse is not known at compile time, I have to allocate dynamically some data in the heap.

After the work is done, the memory in the heap can be released.

My question is simple: I'm releasing the memory correctly? See the questions in the comments.

Tokenize function

```
char** Tokenize(const char delimiter, const char* string)
{
    const char* pString = string;
    char** tokens = new char*[strlen(string)];
    char* buffer = new char[strlen(string)];
    char* pointer = buffer;
    int c = 0;

    for (int k = 0; k < strlen(string); k++)
    {

        if (string[k] == delimiter)
        {
            buffer[k] = '\0';
            tokens[c] = pointer;
            pointer = buffer + k + 1;
            c++;
            continue;
        }

        buffer[k] = string[k];
    }

    tokens[c] = nullptr;
    return tokens;
}
```

The main function which tests Tokenize function and relases the heap.

```
int main()
{
    char** tokens = Tokenize('.', "192.168.1.1");
    char** startTokensPointer = tokens;
    char* startBufferPointer = *tokens;

    while (*tokens != nullptr)
    {
        cout << *tokens << endl;
        tokens++;
    }

    delete[] startTokensPointer; //Releases tokens??
    delete[] startBufferPointer; //Releases buffer??

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: I can't really tell if you deallocate memory correctly. I can tell you that you probably use too much memory and that you need to be very careful to get it to work at all. Just use `std::string` which does basically the same thing except you cannot screw it up if you just remove all `new`s and most pointers from the program. This style of programming is not maintainable.

Comment: You are using C++ syntax, not much point in avoiding its other goodies.  Like std::string and std::map.

Comment: The delete's match the new's, but something looks very wrong with how you use the arrays. ...

Comment: you are right, C++ has std::string, but I want to do some experiments with c-like strings. I see that books of C++ many times start with C-like strings and explain std::string later. It seems like a "must know".

Comment: @deviantfan please, could you be more precise? What's wrong exactly?

Comment: @ErroreFatale: Us experienced C++ programmers have learned it that way too, but in hindsight we realize that it's not the smartest way. What you should know about C is that it was a major inspiration for C++, and the two languages remain quite compatible. That is why C++ keeps some unfortunate constructs that more pure languages would avoid. C strings are such a legacy.

Answer (score 1):

You are not deallocating `buffer` correctly. If none of the chars in `string` is equal to `delimiter` the code in this if statement :

```
if (string[k] == delimiter)
```

will never be executed and `c` will remain `0`. Then this line :

```
tokens[c] = nullptr;
```

will set the first element of `tokens` that is stored in `startBufferPointer` to `nullptr`. In that case you are leaking `buffer` as the pointer to `buffer` is "forgotten" in `main`.

`tokens` is deallocated correctly in all cases.

Comment: Nice that you found the error.

Right: you have to pay attention to nullptr!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is no memory leak, but why not use a type that makes it guaranteed?

```
struct Tokens
{
  explicit Tokens(size_t len) : tokens(new char*[len]), buffer(new char[len])
  { }

  std::unique_ptr<char*[]> tokens;
  std::unique_ptr<char[]> buffer;
};

Tokens Tokenize(const char delimiter, const char* string)
{
    auto len = strlen(string);
    Tokens result(len);
    char* pointer = result.buffer.get();
    int c = 0;

    for (size_t k = 0; k < len; k++)
    {

        if (string[k] == delimiter)
        {
            result.buffer[k] = '\0';
            result.tokens[c] = pointer;
            pointer = result.buffer.get() + k + 1;
            c++;
            continue;
        }

        result.buffer[k] = string[k];
    }

    result.tokens[c] = nullptr;
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    auto tok = Tokenize('.', "192.168.1.1");
    char** tokens = tok.tokens.get();

    while (*tokens != nullptr)
    {
        cout << *tokens << endl;
        tokens++;
    }
}
```

Now all the memory is managed automatically and it's almost impossible to leak.

Comment: I would suggest helping him with his current problem first. Given that he's reimplementing strtok I would guess he's trying to learn & is checking his outcome. Unique pointers are nice but they won't help you work with any legacy code - much of which is being written today - as they still do manual memory management. And as soon as you try a shared_ptr you open up a new can of worms.

Comment: @dascandy, I don't understand the complaint. He is using `delete[]` on the allocated memory, which is a code smell and should be replaced with RAII types. To interact with legacy code use `unique_ptr::get()` to get a raw pointer. That is orthogonal to correct memory management and avoiding naked `delete`s.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but as I wrote I'm studying C++ (not working on actual projects with C++). 
Learning high level things before to understand low level things is against my philosophy. 
I'll continue to manage the memory manually for the first excercices, I'll keep in mind your suggestion for the future.

Comment: @ErroreFatale, it's not a matter of high-level vs low-level, it's "how the language is intended to be used, and how it's designed to work" vs "doing it wrong". See [R.11: Avoid calling new and delete explicitly](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rr-newdelete) and [R.12: Immediately give the result of an explicit resource allocation to a manager object](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rr-immediate-alloc)

Comment: @Jonathan Wakely thanks.
I Imagine that a struct is not necessarily needed. Right?
Can you simply do this? std::unique_ptr<char[]> buffer = new char[length];

Comment: The struct isn't essential, but allows you to return two `unique_ptr` objects at once, and its constructor avoids one of the redundant calls to `strlen` that you had in the original, by using the constructor argument for both array lengths.

Comment: Yes I understand why to use a struct in this case, my question was: you don't use a struct in every case, right?

Comment: Right. If you just want to return one block of allocated memory then you can just return a `unique_ptr`. If you want to return multiple values you need to bundle them together into a struct, or some other data type that can hold multiple objects, such as a `std::tuple`